# Not able to post photo on facebook through android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

#
   Here is my code after login it do not post photo on facebook-#

## This are the permissions i have given:"email", "publish_stream","friends_about_me", "offline_access","friends_birthday","user_location", "user_birthday"

```
    public void onClickSelectContact(View btnSelectContact) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = screenShot(btnSelectContact);

    System.out.println("man man "+bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bos);

   image_array = bos.toByteArray(); 
   System.out.println("man man "+image_array);
    System.out.println("byte array:"+image_array.length);

    facebook.authorize(ac, permissions, new DialogListener() {

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            //params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
            params.putByteArray("picture", image_array);
            params.putString("message", "this myth man");


            try {
            facebook.request(("me") + "/photos", params, "POST");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}   public void onCancel() {
            }});}
```

after login it shows this: 
[when i click ok it just disapear](http://screencast.com/t/nJWqAb89ji)

Comment: go to `https://developers.facebook.com/apps` and select your app and go to `Status & Review` and enable `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?` button

Comment: Please post the complete code. You never set image_array to anything so of course the code doesn't work

Comment: I have aleady enabled it ,currently my app is availabe to all users  Simple Plan

Comment: hey i have post the complete code but there is nothing wrong in image_array, because this code works fine when i run it with diffrent app_id of Facebook android samples.This issue happens only when i used my own registered app_id of facebook

Answer (score 0):

try after adding this permission **publish_actions**.
Check the json you are getting after Request. And in that check that which permission is declined.

```
{
 "data": [
{
  "permission": "public_profile",
  "status": "granted"
  },
  {
  "permission": "publish_actions",
  "status": "granted"
  },
  {
  "permission": "user_friends",
  "status": "declined"
  }
]
}
```

I guess the problem is you are been declined some of the asked permissions.It may be the Reason.
Hope this help.

Comment: am getting this in response  {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200
    }
}

Comment: have u added `publish_actions` this permission ?

Comment: yes  i have added this permission but still getting this error